# How can I hack the IntelliJ Idea Command-line Launcher script to open a file in an independent window and wait for close?

Tags: python, macos, intellij-idea

IntelliJ has a built in [Command-line Launcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html) script that, by default on Mac OS, installs a Python file to `/usr/local/bin/idea`. By examining this file, I was able to find a cool way to launch a file in it's own temporary project (i.e., `idea --temp-project myfile.txt`). What I'd like to do next, is find a way to wait on the project closing.

Again, by examining the Python code, this would seem to depend (at least when IntelliJ is already open, which is my typical usage) upon a socket call `activate ...` (line 88 in the script on my system). At the top of the file, there's a comment that says `see com.intellij.idea.SocketLock for the server side of this interface` which can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/idea/SocketLock.java). Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out the IntelliJ socket API from this file.

Does anyone have a link to documentation or otherwise know a way to hack this, with the goal of basically waiting on the call until the temporary project is closed?

Edit: I'm using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2019.1.3 on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Command line launcher `--wait` key is supported since 2019.2. Running `idea --temp-project --wait myfile.txt` should do exactly what you want: open a file, block cmdline until the file is opened in IDE.

NB: this does not work for Toolbox+Mac, as Toolbox creates incompatible launcher.

Comment: Is it still today (05.2020) possible to use the NON Toolbox Command-line Launcher? if so how? In the net one can only find the toolbox related info